# What causes the polar plot of an ellipse to look different from its parametric plot?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset
{
    urx=15pt,
    ury=15pt,
    llx=-5pt,
    lly=-5pt,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$,
    algebraic,
    polarplot,
    plotpoints=1000,
    tickcolor=gray,
}

\def\x{2*cos(t)}
\def\y{sin(t)}

% r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
\def\r{sqrt(4*cos(x)^2+sin(x)^2)}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[linecolor=gray]{<->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3){\dimexpr6cm-30pt}{!}
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=red]{0}{Pi}{\x|\y}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue,strokeopacity=.5]{0}{Pi}{\r}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What causes the polar plot of an ellipse to look different from its parametric plot? How to fix it?

Comment: I am sorry if my unprecise formulation is the reason of closing your question! I had only in mind, that a pretty good in-topic pstricks problem is caused by a non obvious mathematical reason. I am voting for reopening, with fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iy is rather a mathematical question. If we have point P on the circle `(r\cos(t),r\sin(t))` and the angle between vector OP and axis Ox is `\alpha`, then `\alpha=t`. In an analogous case of (a proper) ellipse `t\neq\alpha`. It means, that your formula definying radius is incorrect. For the equation in polar coordinates see, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315386/ellipse-in-polar-coordinates.